# Question about the lantern pieces in the Winter Toy shop set

Tags: building, design

I have a question about the lanterns in the [Winter Village Toy Shop](https://brickset.com/sets/10199-1/Winter-Village-Toy-Shop).  I'd like to just buy the parts to make a few of the street-lights in that set. However, from reading the instructions (steps 4 and 5 below) and looking at the [globe part](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=61287&tab=V), it doesn't seem like it would be stable. It appears to be just resting inside a 2 x 2 dish, is that right? If so, is there a way to make something like this that's more stable. Or have I just misread the directions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have this piece to check this assembly physically myself to confirm. However, the same design has passed TLG design review not once, but twice: first with 10199 set you mentioned in 2009 as well as 10249 six years later, which is updated version of 10199. So I'm rather confident there is no flaw.

Looking at the picture it seems like [Cylinder Hemisphere 2 x 2 with Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61287#T=P) sit underneath the round plate's ridge, thus making it stable.

[image]

I have built this assembly virtually. Here hemisphere is placed above  round plate's ridge intentionally, to show the fact that hole diameter is smaller. Thus, by placing hemisphere below round plate (as it is shown in instructions) will block it from moving vertically.

[image]

Comment: I have the pieces and I can confirm this is exactly how the connection works and it's very stable. The globe is not going anywhere.

Comment: The pieces also appear in flat silver as The Childs toy in set 75318, however there you have to put the halves not below the ridge but above according to the instructions, so the round plate sticks out more, in order to easily attach it to the childs hand.